# How to ignore a div outside fullpage container in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, frontend, fullpage.js

I have a div outside of the full-page container. How can I scroll normally until the div ends? So each section can be fit into the viewport properly?

example:

```
<div class="dev"> <!-- Div outside the fullpage container -->


</div>


<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      Section 1
      <div class="scrollable-content">
        <h4>Scroll me</h4><h4>Scroll me</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">
          Slide 2.1
           <div class="scrollable-content">
        <h4>Scroll me</h4><h4>Scroll me</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4><h4>Text here</h4>
      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Slide 2.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Section 3</div>
    <div class="section">Section 4</div>
</div>
```

Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zainulabd786/pen/GRRvpEg)

Comment: Look at this example https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/fixedHeaders.html#firstPage. In your case you will just need the header. You can also see this example https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html#anchor1.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to fix the section at top.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the fullpage plugin. Maybe post an an issue on the github repo for help? https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately fullPage.js doesn't allow you to do so.
The most you can do is emulate the normal scroll by using an internal scrollbar within a section, as can be seen [in this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html) that uses the option `scrollOverflow:true`.

You can see some possible approaches by reading this issue, but it will require you use the option `scrollBar:true` and some custom coding:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3205